# Why don't we use continuation passing style always?

Tags: programming-languages, continuation-passing

I've been studying programming language course and I found a thing that I can't get the answer.

I understood that pros about the continuation-passing-style is that we can get rid of the stack overflow by not using the stack frames, just by passing 'what we need to do after' into next operations.

But I find difficulties understanding what is the cons about the continuation-passing-style so the major programming languages are not implemented with CPS.

I will be really happy if someone can help me with this.